# find correct log file out of thousands using head and fgrep

Tags: linux, grep, ip, head

I have thousands of log files - all very large.  One of them is going to have an IP address I'm looking for.  I know it's very likely to occur near the top of the file.  I can do:

```
head -n 500 *.log | fgrep myip
```

and I'll see that "yes", it is in one of the log files.  How do I determine which one?  Grepping the full contents (fgrep myip *.log) of all the files is not possible due to their size.

Comment: IPv4 address???

Comment: Yes, it is an IPv4 address.  Does anyone use anything else ;-)

Comment: Careful with `fgrep` searching for `10.55.33.6` but matching `110.55.33.68`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help.

```
find . -iname "*.log" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} bash -c 'echo "»»»File Name: {}«««"; head -n 500 {} | fgrep -B 501 myip'
```

It will produce a long list of filenames, then upto 500 lines of found data, then a long list of filenames. The filename that you want is the one immediately before the long list of data.

Answer (score 1):

You could get away with just awk:

```
awk -v ip=127.0.0.1 'substr($0, ip) > 0 {print FILENAME ": " $0} FNR > 500 {nextfile}' *.log
```

If the IP was found in the current line, we print it and the filename. We skip to the next file if the current line number for the current file (`FNR`) has become > 500.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name \*.log -print0 |
  xargs -0 sh -c 'for i; do head -n 500 $i | fgrep -q myip && echo $i; done
```

This will find all filenames ending in `.log`, and feed that list to `xargs`. The `-print0` and `xargs -0` are commonly used to use a null byte to terminate the filenames, to protect filenames that contain spaces (a null byte can never be used in a filename so is a safe delimiter).

`xargs` will run the command given after `xargs` and its arguments with as many filenames as will fit in one invocation of the command. In this case the command given is `sh` (the shell), and this shell is given a little shell script to run.

The shell script is basically:

```
for i; do
    head -n 500 $i | fgrep -q myip && echo $i
done
```

The `for i` part loops over all the arguments given to the shell, i.e. all the filenames. For each filename it takes the first 500 lines, and searches for the given string. `fgrep -q` means that fgrep stops as soon as the string is found; if the string is found an exit status "success" is given, else "fail". Finally the `&& echo $i` means that if the preceding command has a "success" status, the echo is performed, meaning that the filename is shown if the string is found.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. loop over all the files
2. grab the first 500 lines
3. see if the IP is in those lines
4. if so, print the filename and end the loop

As code:

```
for f in ./*
do 
  head -n 500 "$f" | grep -qF myip && { printf "Found in: $f"; break; }
done
```

Where you'd replace `myip` with the IP you're looking for. You could create a function (or shell script) that takes the desired IP as a parameter to search for:

```
findlogip ()
{
    for f in ./*;
    do
        head -n 500 "$f" | grep -qF "$1" && {
            printf "Found in: $f\n";
            break
        };
    done
}
```

As [roaima commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449203/find-correct-log-file-out-of-thousands-using-head-and-fgrep#comment815506_449203), you may want to be careful with the IP you're searching for so that you don't accidentally match a different IP (10.55.33.6 but matching 110.55.33.68 in the example). With GNU grep (assumed, given the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag), you could surround the given IP address with `\b` markers:

```
...
head -n 500 "$f" | grep -q "\b$1\b" && ...
...
```

You drop the `-F` (fixed string) grep option, as the expression is no longer a "fixed" one but a regular expression.